# Android: how to prevent multiple instances of an activity to be launched from a widget?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, widget

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- the user launches my app (name of the root activity: "mainActivity") => instance A of mainActivity
- he presses the home button (mainActivity running in background)
- he installs the widget relative to this app
- he clicks on the widget => a new instance of mainActivity (instance B) is displayed
- he clicks on the the back button: the user comes back to activity A (what I don't want ! The activity B should be closed (actually, the whole app should be closed))

Do you know how to avoid this issue ? (I have seen some similar questions on stackoverflow but not stricly what I wanted)

Thanks !!!!

The code:

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Build the intent to call the service//

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);

    Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    openAppIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);
    PendingIntent openAppPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openAppIntent, 0);


    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetLinearLayout, openAppPendingIntent);

//// ETC…///

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
openAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

[description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP).

---

You can also use:

```
openAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
```

[description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT).

Comment: Thanks NeTeInStEiN and Craigy but I still have the same issue... Another idea?

Comment: You need to set the flag whenever you open the activity including in the manifest (which covers launching from the app drawer). This is the correct answer so another idea will not help you.

Comment: Hi Kuffs. I tried to add openAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and then openAppIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) to my onUpdate method by it doesn't work. The issue described in the different steps of my question still occurs. Where am I wrong? By the way, what do you mean by "including in the manifest" ? Thanks.

Comment: He means (i think) to define a launchMode in the manifest. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 2):

I propose using:

```
openAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

This will reuse already existing `Activity` and `onNewIntent` will be called. You can update the UI from there as required.

For more reference check:[Developer.android.com - FLAG ACTIVITY SINGLE TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)

**Edit** 
Launcher Activity is the one which has the following intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

These flags will not work if the widget starts a new TASK which has it's own stack of activities.

I think the best would be to read this article[Developer.android.com - ACTIVITY TASK DESIGN](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html)

Let us know if you find anything.

Comment: Thanks Gyuri but I still have the same issue... Another idea?

Comment: Your `MainActivity` is it the Launcher activity ?

Comment: MainActivity is the activity launched when the app is launched from scratch ; so, yes, I imagine that it is what you call "launcher activity". The problem is that a first instance of MainActivity is launched when the app is launched from scratch and then a second instance is launched by the widget when I click on it. I have then 2 instances superimposed ; when I click on the back button, I go back from the "widget mainActivity" to the "launcher mainActivity". Any idea ? Thanks alot !!!!

Comment: See my response in my Answer box.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve successfully prevented multiple instances of an activity by adding this attribute to the manifest:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

This essentially tells Android that this activity is the Highlander (“There Can Only Be One”), and will prevent it from creating multiple instances. Whenever the activity in question is opened, Android will either bring the existing instance to the front, or in some cases destroy and recreate the current instance.